# Dealing with imbalanced data by using weight

Tags: numpy, import, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have very imbalanced data and the goal is classification. At the first i want to check undersampling on the majority class. Class 1 with 600, class2 90, class3 60 and class4 96 sample data!!!

Using weight: In 2 fold cross validation and Randomforest model:
[image]

Why by using weight, the result isn't better?
 This is my code: `cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=5,class_weight={1:1,2:30,3:30,4:30})`
Is there any thing wrong in my code? Could u please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

The  actual question is **what is your task**. Is your task to maximize the accuracy of the model, even though you have a huge disproportion of classes? If so, you should **not undersample test set**. In fact **you never under- or oversample test set**, you might however, in some cases - add weights to particular classes to make a correction for true priors (which might be different from the empircal ones) or due to cost sensitive learning.

Comment: I tried to use weight. I am using random forest of sklearn, I don't know how should i find an efficient numbers for  weights.  I used cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=5,class_weight={1:1,2:3,3:3,4:3}) but it had no effect. I used higher numbers for group 2,3 and 4 like 10, 20 or even 100. The results were worse.

Comment: sorry, the result is a little better or the same